# Trying to upgrade from CDH4.2 to CDH4.5, but can not Distribute it

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm trying to upgrade from CDH4.2 to CDH4.5 use cloudera Manager.
I click 'download' of CDH 4.5.0-1.cdh4.5.0.p0.30, it shows 100%, but the button still shows 'download', not distribute. I click 'download' again, it stilll the same.

Anybody know what happens?

Thanks,
Xinsong